# can't change matplotlib.pyplot tick marks

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Hello So I'm trying to trying to change the tick mark increments of the following plot to  numbers that are more appropriate ie. increments of 1 on the x-axis and 10 on the y-axis.

[Plot I'm trying to fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjWd8.png)

The code I've tried is bellow:
Any help would be much appreciated!!!

```
import netCDF4
f = netCDF4.Dataset('AVSA.nc','r')

#plot Daily average
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v= f.variables['emissions'][0,0:24,0]

plt.plot(v, linestyle='-',linewidth=5.0, c='c')
plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.ylabel('Emissions')
plt.title (' Emissions 3')
plt.ylim(0, 180)
plt.xlim(0,23)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write and position the ticks directly using:

```
plt.xticks(range(25),[str(i) for i in range(25)])
plt.yticks(range(0,180,10),[str(i) for i in range(0,180,10)])
```

In your code (I generated some data since I don't have your file) you would have:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

v= range(25)#f.variables['store_Bio'][0,0:24,0]

plt.plot(v, linestyle='-',linewidth=5.0, c='c')

plt.xticks(range(25),[str(i) for i in range(25)])
plt.yticks(range(0,180,10),[str(i) for i in range(0,180,10)])

plt.xlabel('Hour')
plt.ylabel('Average Biogenic Emissions')
plt.title ('Daily average Biogenic Emissions March 2013')
plt.ylim(0, 180)
plt.xlim(0,23)

plt.show()
```

, which results in:

[image: changing and positioning ticks]

Comment: Awesome this fixed my problem :) Thank you very much!